# Парсер в питоне выдает пустой список

Tags: python, парсер

Всем привет, пытался сделать парсер на питоне, и вроде как сделал, но он работает через раз. Если просто периодически запускать проект, когда-нибудь выдаст пустой список, хотя изменений не было

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = 'https://www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/movies/top250'
film_url = 'https://www.kinopoisk.ru'

def get_content():
    response = requests.get(URL) #Сохраняем html код
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    # Находим все теги div с class styles_root__3a8vf
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='styles_root__3a8vf')
    films = []
    for item in items:
        #Добавляем в кортеж выборку
        films.append({
            'title': item.find('span', class_= 'styles_mainTitle__3Bgao').get_text(),
            'mark': item.find('span', class_='styles_kinopoiskValuePositive__1G4F6').get_text(),
            'link': film_url+item.find('a', class_='base-movie-main-info_link__3BnCh').get('href'),
            'city': item.find('span', class_='desktop-list-main-info_truncatedText__2Q88H').get_text()
        })
    return films


print (get_content())
```

Comment: Через раз - вам не приходила мысль, что сервер тупо банит ваши частые запросы? Тем более, когда пишете код, всегда есть возможность видеть ответ сервера - что именно прилетает в "пустой" ответ.

Comment: Он выводит : []
Process finished with exit code 0
Как посмотреть в чем ошибка?

Comment: Ошибки ни какой нет, сервер возвращает ответ но так как bs4 не чего не находит то возвращает пустой список.

Comment: Можете для начала попробовать отправлять user-agent. Выведите на печать response.status_code.

Comment: Вывел response.status_code, выводит 200 но список все равно пустой